# Django Admin SelectMultiple Widget

Tags: django, django-admin

In my model I have many to many relationship between 2 tables Users and Groups. 
In the admin interface I see the SelectMultiple widget for Groups. Actually, I am using filter_horizontal, I see the available groups and the selected groups in 2 separate lists.
Is it possible to filter the list of available groups that I can see (based on some criteria). I do not want to show all the groups in the groups table.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In your form class, you can specify a custom queryset for the group-field, which then determines which Group-instances are available in the form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # override the default groups field
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Groups.objects.filter(YOUR_CONDITIONS),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
```